# Adding Restriction Group for a new customer

Tags: acumatica

Customer created restriction group for each customer class and customer classes are assigned to default restriction group.

Eg. Customer Class ABC assigned with default Restriction group All Customer and also a Restriction Group created in the name of ABC.

While creating new customer using Customer class ABC it automatically adds All customer restriction group I am trying to add Restriction group ABC to the customer while saving the customer.

The following Code i have tried and it throws error.

```
public delegate Int32 PersistDelegate(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation);
    [PXOverride]
    public Int32 Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation, PersistDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        Customer cust = Base.CurrentCustomer.Current;
        if (cacheType.Name.ToLower() == "customer" && (operation == PXDBOperation.Insert && cust.BAccountID != null))
        {
            ARAccessDetail grp = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARAccessDetail>();
            grp.Customer.Current = grp.Customer.Search<Customer.acctCD>(Base.CurrentCustomer.Current.AcctCD);
            bool bfound = false;
            foreach (PXResult<RelationGroup> group in grp.Groups.Select())
            {
                RelationGroup row = group;
                if (row.GroupName == cust.CustomerClassID)
                {
                    row.Included = true;
                    grp.Groups.Update(row);
                    bfound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (bfound)
                grp.SaveCustomer.Press();
        }
        return baseMethod(cacheType, operation);
    }
```

**Update**

The above code is not giving any error now, but the restriction group is not enabled for the customer.

Comment: Copy/pasting the error message in your question would help. You can copy error message and stack traces from the Help/Tools->Traces window, details can be expanded to include the stack trace.

Comment: Is the included checkbox being selected properly in the code? If so, is the restriction group active that it is being included in?